# Issues redefining CSS of several li elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, dom

I want to redefine some standard properties (wordpress - as I o not write php myself I have to redefine a lot of things) of my li elements using jQuery, but it doesn't work. Here I want to do it with one list:

```html
<ul class="wpb_image_grid_ul" style="position: relative; height: 453px;">
 <li class="isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></li>
 <li class="isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></li>
 <li class="isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></li>
 <li class="isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></li>
</ul>
```

with the next code:

```js
$(".wpb_image_grid_ul").each(function() {
console.log("try to fit gallery");
$(this > 'li').css({"position": "relative", "float": "left", "margin-left": "0px", "left": "0px", "right": "0px", "background-color": "rgb(50,50,50)"});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I want to change it's css and maybe also deleted predefined styles from an element, but nothing happens with style.
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the `each` function for the ul. But there's only one ul. You should be calling it for your li items instead:

```
$(".isotope-item").each(function() {
    console.log("try to fit gallery");
    $(this).css({"position": "relative", "float": "left", "margin-left": "0px", "left": 
    "0px", "right": "0px", "background-color": "rgb(50,50,50)"});
});
```

As a sidenote, you're positioning all the elements on top of eachother, so you're only going to be able to see one li dot.

Answer (score 0):

There was a small typo with the selector. $(this) => ul, $(this).find('> li') = LI elements collection.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".wpb_image_grid_ul").each(function () {
        $(this).find('> li').css({ "position": "relative", "float": "left", "margin-left": "0px", "left": "0px", "right": "0px", "background-color": "rgb(50,50,50)" });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the way you are trying to access the `li` may not be correct.

Try something like this:

```
$(".wpb_image_grid_ul > li").each(function(){
    // Your code to edit each li in here.
    // You can access each li by using $(this)
    // For example,
    $(this).css("position", "relative");
});
```

This should work! I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should target the `li` elements directly by their classes:

```
<ul class="wpb_image_grid_ul" style="position: relative; height: 453px;">
    <li class="isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">item 1</li>
    <li class="isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">item 2</li>
    <li class="isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">item 3</li>
    <li class="isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">item 4</li>
</ul>

$(".isotope-item").each(function() {
   console.log("try to fit gallery");
   $(this).css({"position": "relative", "float": "left", "margin-left": "0px", "left": "0px", "right": "0px", "background-color": "rgb(50,50,50)"});
});
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mk2g61zr/2/

Answer (score 0):

You want this selector for your each function: `.wpb_image_grid_ul > li`. With the each function, I referenced the iterated elements in the second param of the callback function (el):

```js
$(".wpb_image_grid_ul > li").each(function(idx, el) {
  $(el).css({
    "position": "relative",
    "float": "left",
    "margin-left": "0px",
    "left": "0px",
    "right": "0px",
    "background-color": "rgb(50,50,50)"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="wpb_image_grid_ul" style="position: relative; height: 453px;">
  <li class="isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">1</li>
  <li class="isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">2</li>
  <li class="isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">3</li>
  <li class="isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">4</li>
</ul>
```